# How can I get the text from the TextBox_KeyDown event? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this event and I would like to get the text from the user input dynamically ( real time ) , so when the user type any character, it should be added to the currently text and I have the possibility to get it .

```
 public void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
     TextBox text = (TextBox) sender;
     string myText = text.Text; // will return the old text in the textbox
 }
```

How can I get the new text ( with the key added by the user )??

Comment: Handle the `TextBox.TextChanged` event instead?

Comment: I wouldn't like to use `TextBox.TextChanged` , I need to add the code in this event , if possible

Comment: Can you tell us why? The solution would be dependent on your answer to this.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine , I've other code in this event and it's related to this ( what I've added now ).

Comment: @Dotnet_Developer10 Please [edit] the question and provide a [repro].

Comment: "I would like to get the text from the user input dynamically ( real time ) , so when the user type any character" - user can easily paste large text from clipboard. use PreviewTextInput event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks)

> Usually the TextChanged event should be used to detect whenever the text in a TextBox or RichTextBox changes rather then KeyDown as you might expect.

If you need the `KeyDown` event, obviously you can't rely on the text being set. Otherwise, you should use the [`TextChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event.

**Edit:**

As someone pointed out in the comments, [`OnPreviewTextInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.onpreviewtextinput?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-uielement-onpreviewtextinput(system-windows-input-textcompositioneventargs)) could serve your purpose. You have a bit more control via the [`TextCompositionEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.textcompositioneventargs?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Comment: So , is it not possible to use `KeyDown` event ?

Comment: @Dotnet_Developer10 No, but see my edit.

Comment: What about using propertychanged in the TextBox control?

Comment: You could certainly use `PropertyChanged`.  But `PropertyChanged`is an event, just like the `TextChanged`.  If you don't want to use one event, why would you want to use another?